# I used pip3 to install virtualenv but I can't create venv and also I can't uninstall virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 20.2 with two directories `/` and `/home`.

I used the following command to install virtualenv:

```
>>> sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

It worked fine and it installed in the following path:

```
>>> virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.0.17 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py
```

But when I tried to create an environment I got the following error:

```
>>> python3 -m venv article
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.8-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/username/article_tools/article/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

When I tried to uninstall it to install it using [b]sudo apt install python3.8-venv[/b], I got the following error:

```
>>> sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenv
Found existing installation: virtualenv 20.0.17
Not uninstalling virtualenv at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'virtualenv'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

How can I fix it? By fix, I mean installing virtualenv in a way that I don't get such errors.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions regarding the "apt" package?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm new in linux. I used `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` to install it. I didn't use `apt`.

Comment: Yes, but when you tried to use it, the error message told you that you needed to run another command.  You need to do that.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think you should read my question one more time. I didn't get error when I installed it, I get error when I tried to use it, And now, I even can't uninstall it to try it in another way.

Comment: If you did not type `sudo apt install python3.8-venv`, then you did not finish installing that package.  That's not a separate install, that's part of the install you did.

Comment: @TimRoberts So if it was not finished how do I get `virtualenv 20.0.17 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py` when I type `virtualenv --version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here seems to be that you are mixing up two different packages.

Python 3 comes with a built-in virtual environment module `venv` which is however not installed by default on Debian-based platforms. Like the error message says, `apt-get install -y python3-venv` will install this package, which you can then use with `python3 -m venv`.

`virtualenv` is a separate third-party package which you invoke with the command `virtualenv`.  It's not a bad alternative, but if you are only just learning, I would suggest you simply ignore it for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

For me sudo worked

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo virtualenv venv
source .env/bin/activate
```